# Storing a range of months in an SQL table

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm new to SQL, been learning it for about 1-2 weeks, and I'm stuck on how to store something such as a range of values that could be anywhere between 1 and 6 different ranges.

For example, I'm trying to make a table that stores fish and the time that each fish is available throughout the year (based off the game Animal Crossing). Each fish has a certain set of months in which they are available. For example, a Blue Marlin can be available to catch between January and March, and then June to July, for example (an arbitrary example, probably not right). How could I store this in an SQL database when there could potentially be multiple ranges in which the fish is available?

This is what I've written so far, but it would not be sufficient for a Blue Marlin.

```sql
CREATE TABLE fish (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  start_month INT,
  end_month INT
);
```

One option would be to make 6 different start and end fields, for the worst case scenario where each range is 1 month, with 1 month in between (I believe that's the worst case), or to make a field for all 12 months. But these sound inefficient and verbose.

How could I do this? It would be nice to be able to do a query to check all fish that are available in May, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done using multiple tables. One would be for the other fish data (Name and whatever else) and the other specifically for the months. The ranges should be stored in a range table with a reference using the fish primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE fish (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE fishmonths(
  fishid INTEGER,
  start TEXT
  end TEXT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another table `available` where you will store the available months with a reference to the table `fish`:

```
CREATE TABLE available (
  fish_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES fish(id),
  start_month INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (start_month BETWEEN 1 AND 12),
  end_month INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (end_month BETWEEN 1 AND 12),
  PRIMARY KEY (fish_id, start_month, end_month)
);
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=54c7d83f20c5d54e35240119ff8c84e2).

You can get the availability of each fish with a query that joins the 2 tables:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, 
       a.start_month, a.end_month 
FROM fish f INNER JOIN available a
on a.fish_id = f.id
```

Results like:

```
> id | name        | start_month | end_month
> -: | :---------- | ----------: | --------:
>  1 | Blue Marlin |           1 |         3
>  1 | Blue Marlin |           6 |         7
>  2 | Red Marlin  |           2 |         5
>  2 | Red Marlin  |           8 |         9
```

Or grouped (for MySql):

```
SELECT f.id, f.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
         MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(a.start_month, '%m')), 
         '-', 
         MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(a.end_month, '%m'))
       )) availability 
FROM fish f INNER JOIN available a
on a.fish_id = f.id
GROUP BY f.id, f.name
```

Results like:

```
> id | name        | availability                 
> -: | :---------- | :----------------------------
>  1 | Blue Marlin | January-March,June-July      
>  2 | Red Marlin  | February-May,August-September
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add a months column and use a bitwise flag to store which months are available.

```
January = 1,
February = 2,
March = 4,
April = 8,
May = 16,
June = 32,
July = 64,
August = 128,
September = 256,
October = 512,
November = 1024,
December = 2048
```

The table

```
CREATE TABLE fish (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT,
months INTEGER 
);
```

For a Blue Marlin store 103 in the months column (January, February, March, June & July) 1 + 2 + 4 + 32 + 64 = 103.

```
id | name        | months
1  | Blue Marlin | 103
```

then use the following query to output the results

```
select id, name,
 CASE WHEN (months & 1 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as January,
 CASE WHEN (months & 2 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as February,
 CASE WHEN (months & 4 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as March,
 CASE WHEN (months & 8 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as April,
 CASE WHEN (months & 16 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as May,
 CASE WHEN (months & 32 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as June,
 CASE WHEN (months & 64 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as July, 
 CASE WHEN (months & 128 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as August,
 CASE WHEN (months & 256 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as September,
 CASE WHEN (months & 512 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as October,
 CASE WHEN (months & 1024 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as November,
 CASE WHEN (months & 2048 ) <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as December
from fish
```

Like so

```
id | name        | January  | February | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December
1  | Blue Marlin | 1        | 1        | 1     | 0     | 0   | 1    | 1    | 0      | 0         | 0       | 0        | 0
```

This gives a nice view of each fish and the months it's available with the added benefit you can quickly scan a particular month and see which fish are available.

You can expand on this by changing the case statements to return something other then 1 and 0 if you prefer or change the query to display the ranges of months.

Personally if I was using this for a game I would want to see the layout month by month.

Answer (score 0):

You only have 12 months.  So, have two tables, one for fish and one for each month when the fish is available:

```
create table fish (
    id int primary key,
    name text
);

create table fishmonths (
    fish_id int references fish(id),
    month int check (month between 1 and 12)
);
```

This solves your specific question.  It seems to me that fish do not live their lives on the Gregorian calendar, so not all availability would be on month boundaries.  For a more general solution you should probably ask a new question with more information about what you are trying to represent.